# need assistance with Entry Tkinter in Python 2.5

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Is there a way to make an entry in Tkinter react as you type in the field? I'm wanting this feature for the Quantity section of the code.

It auto generates the label4text when clicking the radiobuttons but not when entering the Quantity.

```
from Tkinter import *

SubnetM = 0

def beenclicked():
    radioValue = relStatus.get()
    return

def changeLabel():
    if relStatus.get() == 'HOSTS':
        if custname.get() == 6:
            label4Text.set("255.255.255.248")
            return
    if relStatus.get() == 'NETWORKS':
        if custname.get() == 6:
            label4Text.set("224.0.0.0")
            return

app = Tk()
app.title("SUBNET MASK CALCULATOR")
app.geometry('400x450+200+200')

labelText = StringVar()
labelText.set("WELCOME!")
label1 = Label(app,textvariable=labelText, height=4)
label1.pack()

relStatus = StringVar()
relStatus.set(None)
radioValue = relStatus.get()
radio1 = Radiobutton(app, text="HOSTS", value="HOSTS", variable=relStatus, command=changeLabel)
radio1.pack()
radio1 = Radiobutton(app, text="NETWORKS", value="NETWORKS", variable=relStatus, command=changeLabel)
radio1.pack()

label2Text = StringVar()
label2Text.set("~Quantity~")
label2 = Label(app, textvariable=label2Text, height=4)
label2.pack()

custname = IntVar(None)
Quantity = Entry(app, textvariable=custname,)
Quantity.pack()

label3Text = StringVar()
label3Text.set("Your Subnet Mask is...")
label3 = Label(app, textvariable=label3Text, height=4)
label3.pack()

label4Text = StringVar()
label4Text.set(SubnetM)
label4 = Label(app, textvariable=label4Text, height=4)
label4.pack()

button1 = Button(app, text="GO!", width=20, command=changeLabel)
button1.pack(padx=15, pady=15)

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `trace()` for `StringVar()` to call `changeLabel` when `custname` was changed.

```
custname.trace("w", changeLabel)
```

I change `custname` from `IntVar` to `StringVar` because `Entry` had problem with converting value to int when it was empty (without number)

I add `*args` to `changeLabel()` because `trace` send some arguments to function.

Full code:

```
from Tkinter import *

SubnetM = 0

def beenclicked():
    radioValue = relStatus.get()
    return

def changeLabel(*args): # require *args for trace
    print "changeLabel", args
    if relStatus.get() == 'HOSTS':
        if custname.get() == "6":
            label4Text.set("255.255.255.248")
            return
    if relStatus.get() == 'NETWORKS':
        if custname.get() == "6":
            label4Text.set("224.0.0.0")
            return

app = Tk()
app.title("SUBNET MASK CALCULATOR")
app.geometry('400x450+200+200')

labelText = StringVar()
labelText.set("WELCOME!")
label1 = Label(app,textvariable=labelText, height=4)
label1.pack()

relStatus = StringVar()
relStatus.set(None)
radioValue = relStatus.get()
radio1 = Radiobutton(app, text="HOSTS", value="HOSTS", variable=relStatus, command=changeLabel)
radio1.pack()
radio1 = Radiobutton(app, text="NETWORKS", value="NETWORKS", variable=relStatus, command=changeLabel)
radio1.pack()

label2Text = StringVar()
label2Text.set("~Quantity~")
label2 = Label(app, textvariable=label2Text, height=4)
label2.pack()

custname = StringVar()
custname.set("0")
Quantity = Entry(app, textvariable=custname,)
Quantity.pack()
custname.trace("w", changeLabel)


label3Text = StringVar()
label3Text.set("Your Subnet Mask is...")
label3 = Label(app, textvariable=label3Text, height=4)
label3.pack()

label4Text = StringVar()
label4Text.set(SubnetM)
label4 = Label(app, textvariable=label4Text, height=4)
label4.pack()

button1 = Button(app, text="GO!", width=20, command=changeLabel)
button1.pack(padx=15, pady=15)

app.mainloop()
```

Tested only on Python 2.7

**EDIT:**

I added few modifications more:

```
def changeLabel(*args): # require *args for trace
    print "changeLabel", args

    custname_int = 0 # default value when error
    try:
        custname_int = int( custname.get() )
    except:
        pass # if error do nothing

    if 2 < custname_int <= 6:
        if relStatus.get() == 'HOSTS':
            label4Text.set("255.255.255.248")
        else: #if relStatus.get() == 'NETWORKS':
            label4Text.set("224.0.0.0")
    else:
        label4Text.set("-")
```

**EDIT:**

This way you can write (almost) only digits in `Quantity`. It will "eat" last char if it is not digit but it can't remove incorrect char betwin digits.

```
def changeLabel(*args): # require *args for trace
    #print "changeLabel", args

    custname_str = custname.get() 
    custname_int = 0 # default value when error

    try:
        custname_int = int( custname_str )
    except:
        if custname_str != "": # if not empty
            custname.set(custname_str[:-1]) # remove last char
            return 

    if 2 < custname_int <= 6:
        if relStatus.get() == 'HOSTS':
            label4Text.set("255.255.255.248")
        else: #if relStatus.get() == 'NETWORKS':
            label4Text.set("224.0.0.0")
    else:
        label4Text.set("-")
```

Comment: That fixes one problem but I need to use a range for determining the subnet mask. example 
    if custname.get() <= "6" and custname.get() > 2:
        label4Text.set("255.255.255.248")
It doesn't seem to let me use a range...

Comment: `custname_int = int(custname.get())` and than `if 2 < custname_int <= 6:` but first you have to check if `custname.get()` get no empty string or (even better) you have to put `int(custname.get())` in `try/except` to catch error when someone writes word (not number)

Comment: I added example to answer - with few modifiactions more.

Comment: I added example which "eat" char at the end if it is not digit.

Comment: OK Everything works magnifico!  Just a question, though. Everytime I save the project I get an error. "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Tk'" everytime I try to run the code....any idea what's causing this?

Comment: In full message you have numer of line with error. It seems you use `Tk` (variable/attribute) in place of `Tk()` (method/function) or you named variable `Tk` but this name is reserved for Tkinter function `Tk()` (because you import library by `from Tkinter import *`)